# Boto3 s3 head_bucket() times out cross region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a boto3 s3 call to check that a bucket exists. My code is running out of us-east-1, and the s3 bucket I am examining is in us-west-2.

I'm able to obtain the s3 client fine which I have tested, and then I call:

```
s3_client.head_bucket(Bucket='mybucket')
```

This call seems to hang forever. When I get some traceback on the error it says: 
    ConnectTimeoutError(botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection at... 'Connection to s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com timed out'.

I have tried the same code with a bucket in us-east-1 and the code returns fine.

Why does the code hang when making this call? Is this a cross region issue?

Comment: Are you using a VPC Endpoint to access S3?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this from EC2? If so, check your security group to make sure this HTTPS egress traffic is permitted.

Comment: Running from EC2 and seems like it should be allowing outbound at port 443 is allowed going out. I found a workaround using s3_west = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-west-2'), and then s3_west.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket='mybucket'). Would prefer to make the call using the s3 client though instead of resource

Comment: This sounds like a bug. What version of boto?

Comment: The build script I am using does 'pip install boto3' so I believe it's the latest version of boto3. Was thinking that if I did not have the right egress rule to have outgoing traffic I would get an error rather than hanging forever... this led me to believe it may be a bug as well. Does boto3 work differently in different regions? What I mean is, can a boto3 call work in us-east-1, but not work in us-west-2?

Comment: The hanging forever just has to do with a packet drop rather than reject. But the fact that it works when you do a different set of boto objects leads me to believe there's a bug in the package with URL formation. Can you run a tcpdump on outbound traffic while you do the non-working and working code so we can see the difference?

sudo tcpdump -i eth0 src <eth0 ip> dst port 443